# Latest updates froze - reboot to emergency mode

Tags: system

After running the updates today I think appcentre said there were 8 updates, it seemed to hang the process while running 2 "operating system" updates. I waited a few hours for it to finish (5 I think) but it never did. I tried to reboot the system but it didn't respond so I (against my better wisdom) forced the appcentre closed and force rebooted. Now I can only boot into emergency mode. I'm not sure what to do now. I'm reading that I should try a live distro and try to fschk the root partition.  I'm about to try that now. 
Anyone know what to try here, or need more info?
I can't seem to get network access in emergency mode; at least I don't know how to...

Comment: Upon reboot I get a message, /dev/sda1: clean. A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9608803308801481.device with a 1minute, 30 second count down. Then it continues and boots to emergency mode. Fsck is clean. I've tried "systemctl reboot" with the same thing and journalctl -xb shows the same error as above with dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9608803308801481.device/start timed out.  That disk is a network SMB drive that I mount at startup.

Comment: OK, so I edited my fstab and commented out that entry. Issued "systemctl reboot", and after the grub menu it booted fine! So thankful...

Comment: You can add your procedures as an answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting out the mount point listed in the error in my fstab solved my problem. I don't have a clue why this became an issue today as I've had that for many many months.  Probably over a year with that setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behaviour yesterday and thanks to Your comments I realized that the last chance I did to my machine was precisely in the fstab file.

I removed the problematic line and voyla! it worked.

here it is the procedure:

1.in the terminal showed while booting Press  CTRL-D to enter emergency mode
2. enter the command `vi /etc/fstab`
3. move to the problematic entry with arrow keys,  in vi you could remove the entire line by pressing  letter D twice
4. Exit vi saving the file by pressing ESC : WQ in secuence
5. Reboot the machine with `systemctl reboot`

This saves Me from reinstalling everything